# How to set path dynamically in crystal report vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

```
    Dim rptDoc As New ReportDocument
    Dim dsRep As New dsReport
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        dt.TableName = "dtReport"
        dt = getReport()
        dsRep.Tables(0).Merge(dt)
```

I want to set this path dynamically because i hate it. too hassle to put the full path.

```
        rptDoc.Load("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Network Drive\8telcomPayrollDTR_2 Final Apr 7\8telcomPayrollDTR\rptReports.rpt")

        rptDoc.SetDataSource(dsRep)
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("startDate", txtFrom)
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("endDate", txtTo)
        rptViewer.ReportSource = rptDoc
        rptViewer.Refresh()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Connection Error", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try
```

Comment: see `Environment.GetFolderPath()`

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Desktop or a Web application ? If it is a Desktop and the report is in the same folder as the exe you can use

rptDoc.Load("rptReports.rpt")

if it is in a subfolder 
rptDoc.Load("SubfolderName\rptReports.rpt")

you cxan also use "..\" ( multiple times) to go to the parent folders